# VBA Copy & Paste Loop ( Generate Field Number)

Tags: vba, excel

Right now im working to generate a label based on quantity in excel. I managed to get it copy & paste based on value from cell. But, i didnt know how to make some cell change according to the loop.

Below is as example :

Current result :

```
| A                                 | B     | C                     | D     | E     |
|-------------------------------    |-----  |--------------------   |-----  |-----  |
| NMB IN DIA                        |       | MADE IN THAILAND      |       |       |
| INVOICE NO                        | :     | MM035639              |       |       |
| C/NO                              | :     | 1                     | /     | 2     |
| SHIP TO                           | :     | A                     |       |       |
| QTY                               | :     | 100                   |       |       |
| NMB PARTS NO                      | :     | SFASDF234             |       |       |
|                                   |       | *SFASDF234*           |       |       |
| CUST PARTS NO                     | :     | SFASDF234             |       |       |
| CUST ORDER NO                     | :     |                       |       |       |
| -----------------------------     | ---   | ------------------    | ---   | ---   |
| NMB IN DIA                        |       | MADE IN THAILAND      |       |       |
| INVOICE NO                        |  :    | MM035639              |       |       |
| C/NO                              |  :    | 1                     |  /    | 2     |
| SHIP TO                           |  :    | A                     |       |       |
| QTY                               |  :    | 100                   |       |       |
| NMB PARTS NO                      |  :    | SFASDF234             |       |       |
|                                   |       | *SFASDF234*           |       |       |
| CUST PARTS NO                     |  :    |                       |       |       |
| CUST ORDES NO                     |  :    |                       |       |       |
```

Expected result :

```
| A                                 | B     | C                     | D     | E     |
|-------------------------------    |-----  |--------------------   |-----  |-----  |
| NMB IN DIA                        |       | MADE IN THAILAND      |       |       |
| INVOICE NO                        | :     | MM035639              |       |       |
| C/NO                              | :     | 1                     | /     | 2     |
| SHIP TO                           | :     | A                     |       |       |
| QTY                               | :     | 100                   |       |       |
| NMB PARTS NO                      | :     | SFASDF234             |       |       |
|                                   |       | *SFASDF234*           |       |       |
| CUST PARTS NO                     | :     | SFASDF234             |       |       |
| CUST ORDER NO                     | :     |                       |       |       |
| -----------------------------     | ---   | ------------------    | ---   | ---   |
| NMB IN DIA                        |       | MADE IN THAILAND      |       |       |
| INVOICE NO                        |  :    | MM035639              |       |       |
| C/NO                              |  :    | 2                     |  /    | 2     |
| SHIP TO                           |  :    | A                     |       |       |
| QTY                               |  :    | 100                   |       |       |
| NMB PARTS NO                      |  :    | SFASDF234             |       |       |
|                                   |       | *SFASDF234*           |       |       |
| CUST PARTS NO                     |  :    |                       |       |       |
| CUST ORDES NO                     |  :    |                       |       |       |
```

As you can see on the expected result, the C/No is loop based on quantity. Not just copy paste. Is there anything I can add?

Below is my current code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E3").Value

    Range("A1:A9", Range("E9")).Copy Sheet3.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do ??

Comment: @Shrikant I want the field C/No also loop based on to total quantity after copy & paste. Right now it just copy all values.

Comment: @Shrikant already get solution based on below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value of the relevant cell to `i`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NewLoc As Range

    For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E3").Value
        'Decide where to copy the output to
        Set NewLoc = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).OffSet(1, 0)
        'Copy the range
        Range("A1:E9").Copy NewLoc
        'Change the value of the cell 2 rows down and 2 rows to the right
        NewLoc.Offset(2, 2).Value = i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @YowE3k...Its works. But i didnt understand how its work actually.

Comment: @Safwan A `Range` object (such as a cell) has a `Value` property.  Setting that `Value` property to something is setting the value in the cell.  So `Range("A5").Value = "xyz"` would be saying place the string `xyz` into cell A5.  In the code I am using the cell at the start of where you are copying to, offsetting that by two rows and two columns, and writing the value of your loop counter to that cell.